# How do I run this python script?

Tags: python, github

I'm new to python, and I was wondering if you could help me run a python script. I'm trying to run a script called PunchBox from Github: https://github.com/psav/punchbox. So far, I have Python 3.9.5 and Git Bash.

In the GitHub page, it says:

To install, clone the repo, cd into it and then execute the following:

```
virtualenv -p python2 .pb2
source .pb2/bin/activate
pip install -U pip
pip install .
```

What does this mean exactly? Where do I run this code?

So far, I tried downloading the zip file from GitHub, installing Python 3.5.9, using cmd, finding the directory with cd, and running that code; but got an error:

> Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. It's also possible that there is a mismatch between the package name in setup.cfg and the argument given to pbr.version.VersionInfo. Project name punchbox was given, but was not able to be found.
>
> error in punchbox setup command: Error parsing C:\Users\Mi\Downloads\punchbox-master\punchbox-master\setup.cfg: Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. It's also possible that there is a mismatch between the package name in setup.cfg and the argument given to pbr.version.VersionInfo. Project name punchbox was given, but was not able to be found.

There's also a requirements.txt that lists additional scripts needed:

```
pre-commit
click
mido
pbr
PyYAML
svgwrite
```

Do these install automatically upon running the script for the first time?

I'm a little confused why I'm getting an error. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you so much!
Giovanni

Comment: You'll note that the instructions you quoted say "To install, clone the repo, ...". That implies using the `git clone` command to obtain the repository. From the error you've shown, it looks like the install needs `git` installed and it needs the directory to be a git repository, rather than the Zip download you used.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I just ran `git clone https://github.com/psav/punchbox.git` from the Command Prompt. Now do I just need to run `virtualenv -p python2 .pb2
source .pb2/bin/activate
pip install -U pip
pip install .`  from the Command Prompt?

Comment: That seems reasonable.

Comment: Hmm, I seem to get this error: `virtualenv -p python2 .pb2
'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Mi\punchbox>source .pb2/bin/activate
'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` Do you know why `virtualenv` or `source` isn't being recognized?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, it looks like you don't have `virtualenv` installed in your system. You may install it using the command `pip install virtualenv`.

Now, as you are using a Windows machine, you may open a `Command Prompt` or `Windows PowerShell` window and navigate to the directory where your cloned project resides.
Now, execute the following commands.

> virtualenv -p python2 .pb2 
> .pb2\Scripts\activate.bat 
> pip install -U pip 
> pip install -r requirements.txt

Once you are done working in your virtual environment (which is named `.pb2`), you may close it by executing `deactivate` command.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are new to programming. You have to write these lines in a terminal.

On Windows, it is `Command Prompt` or `PowerShell Applications` (latter preferred). On macOS, it is `terminal`

Copy all these lines at once, and paste them to your preferred terminal. The terminal will automatically run these one after the another.

**FYI**: Venv is a python package to create a virtual environment. The preceding commands set up the environment. Now install the required dependencies using this command instead of the last command (<del>`pip install .`</del>)

```sh
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I'm on the right track, but I got a few more errors: `RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python2'` ,  `'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` , and `Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository.` Do you know what this means exactly? Thank you again!

Comment: Yep, source command is only supported on Linux or macOS. In windows, use the `activate` command (like `activate .pb2`). Also don't forget to verify this answer and upvote it if it helped 

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried modifying the command, but got another error. Did I enter it in wrong? Also does it matter if I only have Python 3 installed? `RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python2'

C:\Users\Mi\punchbox>activate .pb2
'activate' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Mi\punchbox>virtualenv -p python2 activate .pb2 .pb2/bin/activate pip install -U pip pip install .
RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python2'`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, forgot about that. Run this `.pb2\Scripts\activate.bat` in cmd. Also, try installing virtualenv before using `pip install virtualenv`

Comment: Hmm, now I am getting: `C:\Users\Mi\punchbox>.pb2\Scripts\activate.bat
The system cannot find the path specified.` Do you think this is because the program was written in Python 2.7 but I have Python 3?

Comment: okay, you can try to type `.p` then press tab to autocomplete, then `scr` then tab to autocomplete. If it does not autocomplete, check if the file exists

Comment: Hmm, it seems like .pd2 doesn't exist in the directory. Do you think I missed a step?

Comment: Have you run this already? `virtualenv -p python2 .pb2`

Comment: Also, I think this virtual env is for python2. You have python 3 installed. So maybe installing python2 as well could help..

Comment: Just installed Python 2.7 and it works!! However, I have another silly question. I see a setup.py in the directory, but I'm not sure how to actually run the program (so sorry, I'm new to Python). Do you see how I can turn the program on? [Link to GitHub Directory](https://github.com/psav/punchbox)

Comment: I think run `python2 setup.py` in cmd would do it (or if the file not found error appears, write `python2 `, then drag the setup.py file onto the cmd window), would look something like `python2 C:/kajf/askdjfkl/sdf/dsf/setup.py`

Comment: Also, don't forget to upvote this answer and mark this with a check so that others could find it easily 

Answer (score -1):

**@Giovanni T.**
See, as far as you have installed Python and also downloaded the GitHub Repository as a zip file.

`pip install -r requirements.txt`
Just run this command.

*Please make sure that the directory is pointing to the folder where this requirements.txt file is stored.*

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I'm on the right track, but I got a few more errors: `RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python2'` ,  `'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` , and `Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository.` Do you know what this means exactly? Thank you again!

Comment: `pip install virtualenv` - I see that you might not have installed the virtualenv package yet and also its not mentioned in the requirements.txt. So just execute this command first - `pip install virtualenv`. 

Also, just check here that the command you have mentioned here states - Python 2, whereas you are using Python 3.9 so just make the required changes in the given commands

First, Do this `pip install virtualenv`
Then 


virtualenv -p python2 .pb2
source .pb2/bin/activate
pip install -U pip
pip install .

Comment: Thank you again! Okay, I just installed virtualenv, but the second command gives an error: `RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python2'`. Should I uninstall Python 3 and install Python 2 instead?

Comment: ```virtualenv venv --python=python3.9.5```
```source venv/bin/activate```
```pip install -U pip```
```pip install .```

- Try out this command. Just make sure you are entering the correct Python version. If `python3.9.5` doesn't work - just try out with `python3.9` also.